# Laravel 5 - NotFoundHttpException for update

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a strange situation I am struggling to work out.  I have the following in my route file

```
Route::model('campaigns.campaignEmailLinks', 'CampaignEmailLinks');
Route::resource('campaigns.campaignEmailLinks', 'CampaignData\CampaignEmailLinksController', ['except' => ['index', 'create', 'show', 'edit', 'destroy']]);
```

If I view my routes, I can see what I would expect

```
campaigns/{campaigns}/campaignEmailLinks                            | campaigns.campaignEmailLinks.store
campaigns/{campaigns}/campaignEmailLinks/{campaignEmailLinks}       |
campaigns/{campaigns}/campaignEmailLinks/{campaignEmailLinks}       | campaigns.campaignEmailLinks.update
```

I have a CampaignEmailLinksController with a store and update function.  The form for the create view looks like so

```
{!! Form::model(new App\CampaignModels\CampaignEmailLinks, [
     'class'=>'form-horizontal',
     'route' => ['campaigns.campaignEmailLinks.store', $campaign->id]
 ]) !!}
```

And for the edit view it looks like this

```
{!! Form::model($campaign->campaignEmailLinks, [
     'class'=>'form-horizontal',
     'method' => 'PATCH',
     'route' => ['campaigns.campaignEmailLinks.update', $campaign, $campaign->campaignEmailLinks]
 ]) !!}
```

This is whats weird.  My create view is displayed, I enter data, it saves successfully to my database without any problems.  It then displays the edit page without any issues.  However, if I try to save on the edit form, I get a NotFoundHttpException.

This is the same process as I have handled other models, and none of these have any issues.  The route must be correct otherwise the create would not work, would it?

Am I missing something obvious here?  Is there any way I can get more detailed error information to see what the exact problem is, or where it is?

Any information appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please try method `PUT` instead of `PATCH`

Comment: Same error is being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I think on edit this should be the code:

```
 {!! Form::model($campaign, ['method' => 'PUT', 'class'=>'form-horizontal', 'route' => ['campaigns.campaignEmailLinks.update', $campaign->campaignEmailLinks]) !!}
```

Try once it might work out :)